# How to configure SSL on google app engine with appspot.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, gwt

I am working on project with GWT java on google app engine. I want to use SSL with my application.how shall i use SSL with appspot.com. whats shall i configure to enable SSL on my application

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything for `*.appspot.com` (and you can't, it's Google's domain).

Just use ssl urls, that's it. Use url https://your-app.appspot.com

Comment: thank u Igor for your valuable response, but i tried to access my url like usinf https://   then i cant access my application

Comment: do you get any error? can you provide `curl -v` log?

Comment: and whats is  <security-constraint> used for?

Comment: "not displaying", what you mean? you have connected with SSL successfully, just app fails, right? please provide `curl -v` log, or it'll be really hard to help. 
you can use <security-constraint> if you want to limit you code to _SSL only_. that's not what you're asking right now.

Comment: Actually when i accessing my app with https:// .   then in browser shows like https:// is red crossed  and in browser display message as "your connection is not private"

Comment: check details of this error, maybe there're some hints

Comment: likely not using default version

Comment: Thank you Zig for your valuable response. I deployed on new version and then that version i made default but not working

Comment: what browser say about certificate? please provide output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect your-app.appspot.com:443`

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on GAE but two things come to mind. You can configure your app engine project to forward all http traffic to https. In a java project you'd do this in your web.xml. Second, if you are using a custom SSL certificate that is associated with a custom domain then a *.appspot.com URL will not work. Custom domain specific SSL certs must be deployed at a matching domain.

Comment: @mba12 author was using wrong domain, see another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140478/while-accessing-my-app-using-https-then-not-working-my-app/37142060

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure https for the url in your web.xml file. To quote from google app engine docs :

> To declare that HTTPS should be used for a URL, you set up a security constraint in the deployment descriptor with a "user-data-constraint" whose "transport-guarantee" is CONFIDENTIAL, as follows:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <ustrong textser-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

> Requests using HTTP (non-secure) for URLs whose transport guarantee is CONFIDENTIAL are automatically redirected to the same URL using HTTPS.