# While accessing my app using https then not working my app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, gwt

I am working on app engine project using java GWT.i am accessing my app using https then i can not access my app. why i am not accessing my app with https?
while accessing my app using https browser display as shown in image

[image]

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you specify `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` for those URLs in your `web.xml` file? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, you didn't tell in your previous question that you're using 4th level domain like `vijay.evadev014.appspot.com`, that's important. Google configured SSL certificate for appspot.com only for 3rd level domains, for `*.appspot.com`

As per doc:

> Google does not issue SSL certificates for double-wildcard domains
>   hosted at appspot.com. Therefore with HTTPS you must use the string
>   "-dot-" instead of "." to separate subdomains, as shown in the
>   examples below. You can use a simple "." with your own custom domain
>   or with HTTP addresses.

So if you want to use this certificate you should use url like https://vijay-dot-evadev014.appspot.com

Comment: Thank you so much Igor when i tried access my url with https://vijay-dot-evadev014.appspot.com then i got accessed my app thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

as the error message in your browser states there is a certificate common name mismatch. Your application provides a certificate for vijay.evadev014.appspot.com but you are trying to access sample.myapp.appspot.com

There are two ways to fix this for production:

1. Get a certificate for sample.myapp.appspot.com and make sure your application provides that certificate
2. Change your configuration in such a way that vijay.evadev014.appspot.com points to your application and access it through that address

If its just for quick testing you can always click advanced and ignore this exception **this will not fix the problem for other users**

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you have vijay.evadev014.appspot.com, which is called as second level subdomain of the appspot.com. However, appspot is using wildcard SSL certificate and the certificate issued for *.appspot.com.

[image]

Wildcard SSL certificate can secure only first level subdomains over the common name. You should go through the first level subdomain (like: vijayevadev014.appspot.com) to enjoy secure environment using appspot.